# IntelliJ: Display .java extension in Packages View

Tags: java, file, intellij-idea, package

I am pretty new to IntelliJ and I can't find an option to display all file extension in the packages view (in my case .java).

[image: My problem of the viewer]

As you can see on the sceenshot it just says "Main" or "Controller" on the left package explorer view.

Is there any option to make it display Main.Java and Controller.java (like in the editor view on the right side)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is no such an option.

Comment: I believe it's by design not possible. The circle icon represents a `*.java` file which has been compiled into a `*.class` file. If you create for example an empty `Dummy.java` file it will be shown as `Dummy.java` in the explorer view.

Comment: The Packages view shows classes, not files. Names of classes do not have extensions.

Answer (score 1):

File extension can not be shown in package view(or any other). Rather you can try showing file extension in editors tab. To do this go to File -> Editor -> General -> Editors Tab .
Here select `placement` anything other than none, tick Show file extension . (version IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1)

[image: Here is the view]

Answer (score -4):

Switching "Packages" view to "Project Files" will show extensions:

[image: Project Files]

Comment: Not on my machine. IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.4 (Ultimate Edition)

Comment: Not on my machine either. Ultimate 2018.3

Comment: Not on my machine either. IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3 (Ultimate Edition)

Comment: Not on my machine either. IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.4 (Community Edition)

Answer (score -8):

[An interface is written in a file with a .java extension, with the name of the interface matching the name of the file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mwtu.png)

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_interfaces.htm

Comment: This is not what I mean. I don´t want to change/switch the view. I just want it to show .java in the Packages explorer. To maybe make it more clear: It says sample.fxml but not Main.java. I want it to show the file extension.